# MemoryError while using range() in Python (2.7.4)

Tags: python, python-2.7

Okay, I went through many questions on StackOverflow regarding MemoryError but could not find a satisfactory answer. I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 Gnome 64-bit on my laptop with 2GB RAM. When I write the following Python code -

```
range(987654321/2)
```

It throws a MemoryError. Now I suppose that could be due to less available RAM on my laptop. My doubt is does it depend on whether -

- I have 32-bit or 64-bit version of Python?
- 32-bit or 64-bit Ubuntu?
- If I run it on Windows (ActivePython) altogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on Python2.x, use xrange instead as it is a generator and will not create the entire range in memory, but instead create each iteration as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking Python to construct a list with about 500 million integers.  You don't have enough RAM for that.  If you had enough RAM, on a 64-bit machine, with a 64-bit Python, it would probably work.  But you still wouldn't want to do it - incredibly wasteful.

Comment: Just a comment: you can't say in general that it's incredibly wasteful. It mainly depends on the calculation he wants to perform; keeping all data in memory could in fact increase performance in some cases.

Comment: Yes, I **can** say that.  So there ;-)

Answer (score 0):

That is a very large range to try to use - as it will be looking for contiguous memory 500 million entries each multi byte most at least 4 bytes & you have 2 GB for everything - guess what ***you run out of RAM!***

Use `xrange(493827160)` if you need that big a range.