# I get a memory error while generating prime numbers between two numbers

Tags: python-2.7, primes

My code is correct but I got a memory error while running this code in Ideone.com.

```
m=input()
n=input()

def isPrime(num):
    if num<2:
        return False
    ex=num/2
    for div in range(2,ex+1):
        if num%div==0:
            return False
    return True

def primes(m,n):  
    if m <= 2:
        print 2
        nums=range(3, n + 1, 2)
    else:
        nums=range(m, n + 1,2)

    for num in nums:
        if isPrime(num):
            print num
primes(m,n)
```

Comment: By any chance are you using a very large number for `n`?

Comment: `ex = sqrt(num)` instead of `ex= num/2` could help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MemoryError while using range() in Python (2.7.4)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19263430/memoryerror-while-using-range-in-python-2-7-4)

Comment: thank you...But is still threw an error